# How do I create a new post upon registration with the users first and last name as title

Tags: custom-post-types, php, user-registration

I've been working at this for some time and for the life of me I cannot figure this out. Here is my code as of now.

```
add_action('user_register','create_new_user_profile', 999);

function create_new_user_profile($user_id){
    if (!$user_id>0)
            return;

    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $profile_full_name = $user_info->first_name .  " " . $user_info->last_name;

    $profile_post = array(
         'post_title' => $profile_full_name,
         'post_content' => 'This is the profile post.',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'post_type'    => 'Team',
         'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    $profile = wp_insert_post( $profile_post );
```

}

I've tried several things and searched for some time, the current code returns an empty string, but through other alternatives I've been able to post the username or user_id as the title, but I cant get the display_name or a combination of the first and last name which is what I'm in need of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [get_userdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)  function is what you are looking for. So for the display_name it would be

```
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$profile_display_name = $user_info->display_name;
```

And for first and last name it would be

```
$full_name = $user_info->first_name .  " " . $user_info->last_name;
```

Comment: I've made the additional changes but I still come back with an empty string. I'll edit the original with the changes.

Comment: Is it because the code is taking place during registration and the first and last names are empty when the function fires? I see their first and last names inside their user profile on the back-end.

Comment: The issue was an action that was calling before it ran. Thanks for you help!